# SCSS generates wrong url for background

Tags: css, image, url, npm, sass

I have a project where I use the ReactTS template of DotNet. I installed SCSS and everything works, except for backgrounds.

The images and `scss` are compiled to dist folder (`scss` in the style.css file). All images are compiled correctly and can be called using normal css, but the problem is the `scss`, as the `url()` also contains `dist` in front of the actual url, while the css file itself is already in the `dist` folder. This means that the css looks for an image inside of `/dist/dist/{image}.png}` instead of `/dist/{image}.png}`.

Since I can't just directly edit the `dist/style.css` file, how can I make sure the path will be the correct one?

**Edit:** After changing the URL in the inspector, I can confirm that `/dist/{image}.png}` would indeed work. The problem is that inside of the css, it sais `background-image: url('dist/{image}.png)`, where it should only be `url('{image}.png`. This is inside the `css` file that is generated in the `dist` folder.

**Edit 2:**

**Uncompiled site.scss**

```
html {
    background-image: url('../img/backgrounds/background1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;

    ...
}
```

**Compiled style.css**

```
html {
    background-image: url(dist/fc5316d2f76725be344cc36eb98c28f7.jpg);
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

**Folder structure**

```
├───ClientApp
│   ├───css
|   |   └───site.scss
|   └───img
|       └───background1.jpg
└───wwwroot
    └───dist
        ├───style.css
        └───fc5316d2f76725be344cc36eb98c28f7.jpg
```

**Edit 3:**

**webpack.config.js**

```
    ...

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
            { test: /\.s?css$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'] }) },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        ...
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css'
        })
    ]

    ...
```

Comment: why does your scss contain `dist/`in the url ? or better can you pls post your scss and your compiled css for better understanding whats happening ?

Comment: @Dirk See edit 2

Comment: thanks. interesting that your setup removes all folders when it creates the dist. for the replacing of the path in url, that might be a problem with your npm/gulp/webpack (or whatever you are using) config, scss it self will not do this

Comment: @Dirk Added the webpack congif file.

Comment: ok, i might have an idea. can you change `publicPath` to `path: './dist/` ? or better `path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')` if you include `const path = require('path');` at the top. but maybe im totally of and you set publicPath for a good reason

Comment: @Dirk Second option doesn't work at all, first one just adds an error. The website will function though. The url is still wrong

Comment: strange the second option is directly from https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/ and just uses part of nodeJS to resolve the path to dist folder, it should work, .... i just saw you have path already defined, my bad. in that case, just remove `publicPath`

Comment: @Dirk removing the publicPath will return an error saying I have to specify a publicPath in the output section

Comment: okay then change it into `'/'`

Comment: @Dirk Than the file url becomes `/{image}.jpg` instead of `dist/{image}.jpg`

Comment: well then if if your html file is in the same folder `./`should do the trick

Comment: @Dirk That's it, thanks!

Comment: no problem, glad i could help